# Write a program that calculates N! / K! for given N and K.in Java - overflow problem

Tags: overflow

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CalculateAgain {

    public static void main (String[] Args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            long N = input.nextLong();
            long K = input.nextLong();
            double result = 1;
        while ( N > K) {
            result*=N;
            N--;
        }
            System.out.printf("%.0f", result);

    }
}
```

I am unable to print bigfactorial numbers. I have tried with the variable result as long but when I `println` it I get wrong result.

I have also tried to use BigDecimal but I cannot cast it to long or double.

I am quite a beginner - I have learned loops, arrays, conditional statements. I have no understanding of methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `import java.math.BigInteger;`

try this way, after scanner. Assuming I am using `BigInteger`, you can change as per your requirements.

```
  int n = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
  int k = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());

  BigInteger result = new BigInteger("1");
        int range = n - k;
        for (int i = range; i > 0; i--) {
            result = result.multiply(new BigInteger(String.valueOf(n)));
            n--;
        }
```

Comment: thank you so much for your help! I spent 3 hrs yesterday trying to figure it out. I knew the limits of int so I was using long, double but with double it never gives an accurate result.

Comment: Glad to hear that it helps you.